# Loading Images and showing it on my ImageView on my Profile Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this social shopping application that I am making and it requires users to register and upload a profile picture and other information that is required then I had tried to display static images in my android project but now since i am about to go live.

My problem is how can I let users upload images and also retrieve the uploaded image to be set as a profile picture of the user

Comment: I think you need to be abit more specific. But you should probably look at how to encode and decode images to base64. Then you can upload your images as a String and download images as a String and then convert into bitmaps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383833/upload-picture-to-server